# TCPDF ERROR: Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0

Tags: php, jasper-reports, tcpdf

TCPDF ERROR: Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0

My code:

```
include_once('class/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

include_once("class/PHPJasperXML.inc");
include_once ('setting.php');

$xml = simplexml_load_file("Relatorio/relatorio.jrxml"); //informe onde está seu arquivo jrxml

$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
$PHPJasperXML->debugsql = false;
$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$PHPJasperXML->connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I", "");
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: There's no setPage() in the code you included.

Comment: I guess your report is empty set whenNoDataType="BlankPage" on jasper report tag